# Modificar atributo "lang" del tag HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Llevo bastante rato con este tema y no hay manera de encontrar solución. Quiero modificar el atributo lang del HTML de forma dinámica en función del idioma de usuario (que cargaré después de hacer login, ahora tengo el dato hardcodeado para ver si funciona).

Sin embargo, a pesar de haber indicado que quiero modificar el atributo "lang" mediante el método "attr", no hay manera, y no entiendo porqué.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("html").attr("lang", "gl-ES")
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el resultado, cuando ejecuto, compruebo que pasa por la línea mediante punto de interrupción. Veo que pasa, continuo la ejecución y, cuando voy a ver el código fuente de la página, veo que sigue igual.

[image: Debugando]

[image: Detalle]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

**En realidad tu código es correcto y cambia el valor del atributo `lang` de `"es-ES"` a  `"gl-ES"`, lo que sucede es este cambio no es representado en el código.**

Como muestra, este otro ejemplo, en el cual se cambia el valor del atributo `href` de `href="https://www.google.com/"` a `href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/` y del atributo `src` cambiando la url de la imagen, lo cual realiza sin problema, pero esto no se refleja en el código:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a").attr("href", "https://www.stackoverflow.com/")
                $("img").attr("src", "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg")
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript cambia valor de atributo href</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="myLink">Go to Google?</a>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   

<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, puede parecer una chorrada pero, si dices que no se representa en el código, ¿Cómo sabes que ha cambiado? ¿Cómo puedo estar seguro que se ha modificado si no tengo forma de comprobarlo?

Comment: En lugar de comprobarlo en el código fuente, tendrías que abrir el inspector de código del navegador para ver en tiempo real la modificación del atributo que has hecho